# Missing links to Meta chat rooms

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, hyperlinks

Meta Stack Overflow has its own set of [chat rooms](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com) at chat.meta.stackoverflow.com.

But you can't get there.  The "Stack Exchange" dropdown on the upper-left has the "chat", "blog" and "logout" links associated to the main site when viewed from Meta. OK, fine.  It's a missed opportunity for a shortcut, but at least it's consistent with being on the same line as Stack Overflow main.

[image]

But the "chat" link at the bottom also links to main chat (chat.stackoverflow.com).

[image]

And the chat rooms displayed on the meta main page are from main site chat as well.

[image]

I think that at least the chat link in the bottom bar, when displayed on Meta, needs to go to Meta chat.

Answer (score 16):

They're not MSO chatrooms anymore - they're MSE chatrooms, linked to from https://meta.stackexchange.com/ and located at https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/

The old http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/ URL just redirects.

See: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/

Comment: I know about meta.SE... nothing in that announcement said anything about chat.  We need meta chatrooms for SO.  Whether those are associated with meta.SO or directly with SO and have a mission of meta activities doesn't matter so much, as long as links start showing up in meta.SO

Comment: Well, [there's this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5/the-so-tavern-general)

Comment: No other site (that I know of) has its own meta chatrooms linked specially, so I don't think it's particularly surprising that this one doesn't either now, is it?