# General and Review chat rooms on chat.stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

I sometimes get some simple questions while browsing, answering or reviewing posts on stackoverflow. These questions are not really questions that need to be posted on meta.stackoverflow as they are simple common questions and will mostly end up a duplicates or posts with many negative votes as I might not be doing an efficient search and are more suited to ask someone in a chat room. The questions I am talking about are for example

While reviewing I found a specific post which might not be a right fit on stackoverflow might need to be migrated to the right site (superuser, programmers, dba) ?

What is the right flag to choose for a specific post on stackoverflow?

What is the right site (stackoverflow, superuser, programmers, dba) to post a specific question ?

I know from [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260726/2246380) answer that there is no chat for meta.stackoverflow and questions must be redirected to chat.meta.stackexchange but these questions might need some technical skills to provide the right answer and not suited for meta.stackexchange.

Hence I feel there is a need for General and Review chat rooms in chat.stackoverflow. These rooms will have a couple of mods, high rep users or experienced users to help out anyone with such questions. This will help reduce the number of duplicate questions and negative vote posts on meta and stackoverflow and can help increase the overall quality of posts.

Personally I would love to have a Review chat room open in the next tab while doing reviews to ask quick questions and similarly have General chat room open which asking or answering questions.

Answer (score 4):

There's already quite a few active rooms focusing on certain languages on SO chat, with very experienced/high rep users that already do discuss such matters as reviewing suggested edits, if something should be flagged, if something should be closed/any other issues raised.

If you're suggesting there should be some sort of centralised room for this thing, there's already the "Close Votes Room" which have meetings for that purpose, and for general enquiries (although they're more general than specialist knowledge), you've always got "The Tavern" on Meta Stack Exchange Chat.

In short, it's generally quite easy to see a post is just "rubbish" from the offset, although with different skill-sets I believe it'd be difficult to have a single room with sufficient cross-skills to actually make it practical... Although, I would like to see one though :)

Comment: I thought Close Votes Room is only for discussing Close Vote review queue. So can I post questions related to First Posts and Late Answers in it?

Comment: I am talking about having some basic technical skill to judge where a question needs to be migrated or whether to close some question as too broad or off topic not domain expertise. I can distinguish rubbish but for questions with are not just the right fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: @Srikanth ah huh... I think I understand you somewhat better now... but for migration for instance, that's always a tricky one... experience in a language/two can determine if it's meant to be SO/programmers/codereview

Comment: @Srikanth I'll also mention that as you've mentioned "close" - that covers migration/off-topic and too-broad... and communities in active and major tags do tend to "self-manage" - which is the point of the system and how it works

Comment: Jon Clements -  feel free to edit my question to make thinks more clear if you can. I am not good at asking questions

Comment: Jon Clements -  I agree. I just mentioned a random example. btw I can't use @ in my firefox browser thus using different syntax